# Ripple effect does not work in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout, rippledrawable

I'm trying to implement ripple effect in a `RelativeLayout` on API 22 but it doesn't show up. However the same ripple works in a `Button`.

The code for my ripple drawable is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#d1c4e9">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rect"/>
</ripple>
```

Code for Relative Layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple">
</RelativeLayout>
```

After this the ripple is set as a background on `Button` and `RelativeLayout`. The ripple on button works great but it doesn't show up on the `RelativeLayout` at all.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is this ripple object class coming from?

Comment: Is the drawable in drawable-v21?

Comment: Holmes: sorry, i didn't get your question?

Comment: Raghunandan: yes, its in drawable-v21 and works perfectly for a button but not for relative layout

Comment: @VarunKumar what happens when you click on `RelativeLayout`. Do you any other child views taking focus??. Post your relative layout code. the xml. lets see if we can reproduce your problem

Comment: @Raghunandan Nothing happens when I click on the RelativeLayout.

Comment: @VarunKumar post your codes.

Comment: @Raghunandan I even get the background color which I have set by help of rect drawable inside the ripple drawable given in the code above. But ripple does not take place when I click on the relative layout

Comment: @Raghunandan code posted above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86693/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-varun-kumar).

Comment: refer my answer below

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Adding this attribute `android:clickable="true"` works. Tested on Nexus 5

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what Rahunandan said, if you are using appcompat-v7 support library you also need to add 
`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` .

Comment: how are you supposed to add another background attribute when you already have one???

Comment: If you already have a background attribute you can set a foreground attribute instead. Try experimenting with what works best for your UI. Try setting the existing background as foreground and the `selectableItemBackground` as background. If setting foreground doesnt work for you, you can add a `LinearLayout` outside of your view and set `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on the `LinearLayout`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: you're right, it does help big time! So what I did was just to set it as my foreground, I have actually done that before but the color I used was not obvious, now It does. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This attributes in the layout.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this works (API 23 and above)

```
    android:background="@drawable/your_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case ripple effect is working after the first click, but for first click it didn't work for me. Have changed the background selector file with **android:state_activated="true"** and in main.xml **android:clickable="true"**  then it's work fine for all time.

selector.xml (under res\drawable\selector.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/card_bg_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/card_bg_focused" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/card_bg_selected" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

In activity_main.xml

```
 <com.mysample.RecyclingImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_overlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: what do you mean? there doesn't seem to be a ripple here.